# Intermittent Firefox DNS-over-HTTPS failure

Tags: firefox, dns, browser, doh

**Background & Configuration**

I have enabled DNS-over-HTTPS (DoH) in Firefox, in order to hand a stream of sites I access over to Cloudflare and thence directly to government agencies in one convenient place. This is hidden away in *Preferences*, *General* tab, scroll down to the bottom right, *Settings* button, scroll down to the bottom again.

I noticed on attempting to search for a term containing a dot, that DNS-over-HTTPS was not being used. My ISP, BT, were still hijacking plain old DNS to redirect to their site. This is surprising given the wording provided by Firefox that indicates to any reasonable person that this would be safe. Firefox UX sign-off could do with bucking their ideas up, IMO.

So, after googling I have gone into `about:config` and changed `network.trr.mode` to `3` in order that Firefox does not **fail unsafe on DoH**.

This doesn't work at all.

Further googling, I have switched off the BT *"Smart Setup"* on my ADSL router. The steps for my BT Home Hub:

- Log in to the admin site *192.168.1.254*.
- *Advanced Settings*
- *Continue to Advanced Settings* (!)
- *Home Network*
- *"Smart Setup"* (It seems "smart" is never smart.)
- *No*
- *Apply*

That seemed to work for a while, but then failed and kept failing.

It's an intermittent failure. Switching `network.trr.mode` back to `2` (fail open!) and then possibly loading something, allows setting `network.trr.mode` back to `3` for a while.

I suspected that Firefox may be doing all the lookups outside of DoH using just the poisoned DNS cache. However, sites I had not been to still worked.

Going to https://1.1.1.1/help during intermittent failures gives me:

```
 Connected to 1.1.1.1           No
 Using DNS over HTTPS (DoH)     No
 Using DNS over TLS (DoT)       No
 AS Name                     Checking...
 AS Number                   Checking...
 Cloudflare Data Center         LHR
```

When working that becomes:

```
 Connected to 1.1.1.1           Yes
 Using DNS over HTTPS (DoH)     Yes
 Using DNS over TLS (DoT)       No
 AS Name                     Cloudflare
 AS Number                     13335
 Cloudflare Data Center         LHR
```

Going to https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/encrypted-sni/ I noticed that Encrypted SNI was not happening. As I understand it, SNI enabled a web server to provide the correct certificate for a site when a single IP address is mapped from multiple names. Unfortunately, by default, **Firefox sends host names in plain text even when using DoH**. Believable.

Yet more googling turns up setting `network.security.esni.enabled` to `true` in `about:config` to encrypt host names here. How this fails, I don't know.

I have also tried using a public access point (The Cloud), and the behaviour is much the same.

I have been using macOS Catalina. Seems to be the same on a Windows 10 cheap and very nasty laptop. Have tried flushing the Windows DNS cache with `ipconfig /flushdns` and also setting `network.dnsCacheExpiration` to `0`. Neither makes it work when it is failing, nor makes it fail when it is working.

**The question**

What is causing fail-safe DoH that intermittently fail on Firefox and how do I fix it?

I notice that the `www.cloudflare.com` name is in the DoH configuration. Is it failing to bootstrap in a sensible fashion? Does it expire the lookup after a while and not use DoH in time?

Comment: You mention the dns cache, but have you flushed it when you experience these failures? Obviously thinking that the machine may actually be resolving a bad address locally.

Comment: @Yorik I haven't. So: What's the correct way of flushing the Firefox DNS cache. Going to *History* > *Clear Recent History*, provides a number of options, none of which explicitly says DNS. Secondly, you mean flushing before switching instead of setting mode back to 2, rather than flushing to see if it fails when working (obviously, I can try both).

Comment: I mean that if it is cached, it *may* be using the cache and never reaching out to the world for information so you would not need to change any settings in your application. Probably not, but try it for "due diligence." This would be a Windows DNS cache. open a `cmd` window as administrator and `ipconfig /flushdns` ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ipconfig ) or power shell ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/clear-dnsclientcache?view=win10-ps )

Comment: @Yorik I should have said, I am using macOS Catalina. Though I do have a cheap and nasty Windows machine at home to play with.

Comment: RIght, sorry. Most if not all modern OS cache DNS. The steps vary by version for MacOS. Google "mac os flush dns cache"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now had a look at the [wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Trusted_Recursive_Resolver).

It turns out that it is indeed the issue of bootstrapping the name used in the resolver HTTPS URL. An IP of a DNSSEC server needs to be in `network.trr.bootstrapAddress`, probably using the same server as for DNS-over-HTTPS. The wiki suggest looking up with https://dns.google/query?name=mozilla.cloudflare-dns.com which can be checked with `nslookup`. For Cloudflare this gives the choice `104.16.249.249` or `104.16.248.249`. The [initial ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1434852) also suggests the alternative of using an IP address in HTTPS URL (though I guess that means it would be using an IP address HTTPS certificate).

So beyond the preferences window, the configuration you need in `about:config` to make DNS-over-HTTPS work in Firefox appears to be:

```
 network.security.esni.enabled    true
 network.trr.mode                 3
 network.trr.bootstrapAddress     104.16.249.249
```

**All I wanted was a ticky box.**

**Edit:** It's difficult to reproduce, but I still see the intermittent problem. It occurs for one page then clears itself.